# Geometry Emission Shader in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, geometry-shader

I'm working on trying to create a cg shader that emits a quad from each vertex of a mesh. I know I'm looking at making a Geometry shader, but can't find any documentation or examples of geometry addition shaders that play well with Unity - most only modify existing vertices in the vertex subshader.

For every vertex on the mesh, I am essentially looking at creating a particle system comprised of quads created at each existing vertex on the mesh.

Thanks in advance for any guidance or resources!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an [old answer of mine elsewhere](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1065843/view.html) as a basis, you need the folowing:

- `#pragma geometry geom`
- `[maxvertexcount(N)]`
  `void geom(triangle v2g IN[3], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream)`
- And some code to turn the input verticies into output verticies.

Note that the above example takes in full triangles at a time, although [there are other types](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2120983&seqNum=2). Second thing to note is the `N` in the annotation, that is you telling the GPU how many verticies you're sending back. In my case, I was sending 12 (4 for each edge in the original triangle), in your case you can use GL_POINTS and take in a single vertex and output 4 as a quad (so `N` would be `4` for you). See also the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on how to declare the `geom` function for other inputs.